# 'addnewcus_form' object has no attribute 'save_cusdetails' error in django

Tags: python, django

I am new to django. I gave my code bellow. Any one can help me please? I cant find out where the mistake. Thanks in advance.

**addnewcus.html**

```
<form id="addnewcus_form" method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
     <ul>
         <li id="li_1">
             <label class="description" for="id_bname">Customer Name </label>
             <div> {{ form.cname }} </div>
          </li>
          <li id="li_2">
              <label class="description" for="id_bauthor">Customer Address </label>
              <div> {{ form.caddress }} </div>
          </li>                 
      </ul>
</form>
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class cusdetails(models.Model):
   cid=models.IntegerField()
   cname=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   caddress=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',url(r'^addnewcus/$', 'cusapp.views.addnewcus_view', name='url_addnewcus'),)
```

**forms.py**

```
import random

def get_rand_no():
    return random.randint(1234567, 9999999)
class addnewcus_form(ModelForm):
   cname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
   caddress = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())

    class Meta:
        model = bookdetails
        exclude = ('cid','active')


    def save_cusdetails(self):
        cusdetail_data = self.cleaned_data
        randomnumber = get_rand_no()
        cusdetails_createobj = cusdetails.objects.create(cid=randomnumber, cname=cusdetail_data['cname'], caddress=cusdetail_data['caddress'],active=True)
        return cusdetails_createobj
```

**views.py**

```
def addnewcus_view(request, template_name="addnewcus.html"):
     if request.method=="POST":
          cusdetail_data=addnewcus_form(data=request.POST)
          if cusdetail_data.is_valid():
              addcusdetail_obj = cusdetail_data.save_cusdetails()
              return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("url_index"))
          else:
              return render(request, template_name,{'form':cusdetail_data})
     elif request.method=="GET":
          cusdetail_data=addnewcus_form()
          return render(request, template_name,{'form':bookdetail_data})
```

when i hitting the url, It shows the following error.
**'addnewcus_form' object has no attribute 'save_cusdetails' error in django**

Comment: Sounds like you declared your `save_cusdetails` outside of the class. Check your indentations.

Comment: here only indendation is not correct. In my code i wrote def inside of the class only

Comment: @ijarlax: please fix your code snippet so it is _exactly_ like your real code, else we cannot help.

Comment: i edited the above code & its the original code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your forms.
python is whitespace sensitive programming lang.
when you write:

```
class A(object):
    def foo():
        pass

def boo():
pass
```

then boo() will not be in the class scope. it will be in module scope.

Comment: thanks for your reply Zagorulkin Dmitry. Here only my indentation is not in proper order. sorry for that. In my code indentation is correct.